# ffmpeg concat mp4 files doesn't work properly on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, ffmpeg

I'm trying merge two mp4 files with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp4 -i video.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

Locally it works good. But on AWS Lambda it doesn't work properly, ffmpeg merged only first 4-5 seconds of audio.mp4 and rest part of output.mp just video without audio. How can I fix that?

Comment: Any error messages in the CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function? Any error messages from ffmpeg?

Comment: No, processing without errors.

Comment: I would rerun ffmpeg with max verbosity, both locally and in Lambda, to try and work out what the difference is. Were both fmpeg binaries built with the same options, for example. Does the Lanbda environment have enough RAM and CPU?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transcode with cloud services, Lambda is not the correct way to do it. You can use services like AWS Elastic Transcoder,

https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/

Process goes like this,

S3 (audio.mp4, video.mp4) --> Elastic Transcoder --> output.mp4

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks interesting. Elastic Transcoder can concat two files?

Comment: AWS error: At least one media file (input #2) doesn't match the others. All media files must have either video or no video.

Then it can't merge audio and video.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/audio.html . Yes, you can do all fun with elastic transcoder. You need to take time to read those.

Answer (score -2):

I move everything on beanstalk.